# Using multiple ingress controllers with single Ingress resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two Ingress Controllers using the same Ingress Resources, in order to avoid a bottleneck. Why must I add annotations? Is there any unexpected behaviour what can result from having two controllers for the sam ingress resource?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to add an annotation.

Be careful when using Ingress Controllers there is a bug in the code that causes cyclic crashing.